# Dell Service Tag Request using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, soap

I'm trying to get VBA to work with the Dell SOAP interface. 
I think I've got about 99% of the way there as the request is successfully returning the data I asked for to cell A5.

I cannot however get the **SystemModel** node value.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Set and instantiate our working objects
Dim sURL As String 
Dim sEnv As String
Set xmlhtp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
sURL = "http://xserv.dell.com/services/assetservice.asmx?WSD"


 ' we create our SOAP envelope for submission to the Web Service
 sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "   <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
 sEnv = sEnv & "   <soap:Body>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "   <GetAssetInformation xmlns=""http://support.dell.com/WebServices/"">"
 sEnv = sEnv & "   <guid>12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012</guid>"
 'Looks for SKU in active worksheet cell B3
 sEnv = sEnv & "   <applicationName>AssetService</applicationName>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "   <serviceTags>" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & "</serviceTags>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "   </GetAssetInformation>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "   </soap:Body>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "   </soap:Envelope>"
' Send SOAP Request
With xmlhtp
    .Open "post", sURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Host", "xserv.dell.com"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    .setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://support.dell.com/WebServices/GetAssetInformation"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept-encoding", "zip"
    .send sEnv
    xmldoc.LoadXML .responseText
    xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"
    Set xmlElement = xmldoc.DocumentElement
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Value = .responseText
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = .SelectSingleNodes("//GetAssetInformationResult/Asset/AssetHeaderData/SystemModel").Text
   MsgBox xmlElement.SelectNodes("Body/GetAssetInformationResult/Asset/AssetHeaderData/SystemModel").Text

End With 
Dim xmltemplatestring As String
Set xmlRoot = xmldoc.DocumentElement
Set xmlChildren = xmlRoot.ChildNodes

 For Each xmlTemplate In xmlChildren
xmltemplatestring = xmltemplatestring & xmlTemplate.nodeName
Next xmlTemplate

MsgBox xmltemplatestring

End Sub
```

These two lines do not work and generally gets runtime error 438

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = .SelectSingleNodes("//GetAssetInformationResult/Asset/AssetHeaderData/SystemModel").Text
MsgBox xmlElement.SelectNodes("Body/GetAssetInformationResult/Asset/AssetHeaderData/SystemModel").Text`

**xmltemplatestring** returns **soap:Body**

A5 contains the following text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetAssetInformationResponse xmlns="http://support.dell.com/WebServices/"><GetAssetInformationResult><Asset><AssetHeaderData><ServiceTag>7Y5WR4J</ServiceTag><SystemID>poweredge-r510</SystemID><Buid>202</Buid><Region>Europe</Region><SystemType>PowerEdge</SystemType><SystemModel>PowerEdge R510</SystemModel><SystemShipDate>2010-05-30T19:00:00-05:00</SystemShipDate></AssetHeaderData><Entitlements><EntitlementData><ServiceLevelCode>NU</ServiceLevelCode><ServiceLevelDescription>ND ProSupport EndUser On-Site Extended with Dates</ServiceLevelDescription><Provider /><StartDate>2015-05-30T00:00:00</StartDate><EndDate>2016-05-31T00:00:00</EndDate><DaysLeft>316</DaysLeft><EntitlementType>Active</EntitlementType></EntitlementData><EntitlementData><ServiceLevelCode>NU</ServiceLevelCode><ServiceLevelDescription>ND ProSupport EndUser On-Site Extended with Dates</ServiceLevelDescription><Provider /><StartDate>2013-05-30T00:00:00</StartDate><EndDate>2015-05-31T00:00:00</EndDate><DaysLeft>0</DaysLeft><EntitlementType>Expired</EntitlementType></EntitlementData><EntitlementData><ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode><ServiceLevelDescription>Next Business Day Onsite</ServiceLevelDescription><Provider /><StartDate>2010-05-30T00:00:00</StartDate><EndDate>2013-05-31T00:00:00</EndDate><DaysLeft>0</DaysLeft><EntitlementType>Expired</EntitlementType></EntitlementData><EntitlementData><ServiceLevelCode>4I</ServiceLevelCode><ServiceLevelDescription>4H ProSupport For IT Mission Extended with Dates</ServiceLevelDescription><Provider /><StartDate>2010-05-30T00:00:00</StartDate><EndDate>2013-05-31T00:00:00</EndDate><DaysLeft>0</DaysLeft><EntitlementType>Expired</EntitlementType></EntitlementData></Entitlements></Asset></GetAssetInformationResult></GetAssetInformationResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could find it recursively through the child nodes

eg

```
Set xmlElement = xmldoc.DocumentElement
Set SystemModel = FindChild(xmlElement, "SystemModel")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = SystemModel.Text

Function FindChild(ByVal rootNode As Object, ByVal nodeName) As Object
Dim node As Object
Dim tempFind As Object

    For Each node In rootNode.ChildNodes
        If rootNode.nodeName = nodeName Then
            Set tempFind = node
        Else
            If node.nodeTypeString = "element" Then
                If tempFind Is Nothing Then
                    Set tempFind = FindChild(node, nodeName)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next node
    Set FindChild = tempFind
End Function
```

where FindChild(xmlElement, "SystemModel") passes an XML node and the nodeName to search

Also, there are multiple namespaces in the XML so you need to include them and also ensure they are prefixed to allow the correct path to be defined. This should work

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    xmldoc.LoadXML .responseText
    xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
    "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' " & _
    "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " & _
    "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' " & _
    "xmlns:mm='http://support.dell.com/WebServices/'"
    Set xmlElement = xmldoc.DocumentElement
    Set SystemModel = xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("//soap:Body/mm:GetAssetInformationResponse/mm:GetAssetInformationResult/mm:Asset/mm:AssetHeaderData/mm:SystemModel")
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = SystemModel.Text
   MsgBox SystemModel.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: That works - Thanks- sorry I can't mod your answer up yet.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectSingleNodes` is not an existing method, and `SelectNodes` returns a nodelist, so you have to select a specific member of that list before trying to access its properties.

Try:

```
 xmlElement.SelectNodes( _
 "Body/GetAssetInformationResult/Asset/AssetHeaderData/SystemModel")(0).Text
```

Comment: That isn't working - still getting runtime 438 with MsgBox .xmlElement.SelectNodes("Body/GetAssetInformationResult/Asset/AssetHeaderData/SystemModel")(0).Text  - I'm assuming this is within the xmlhtp object?